# Karate API - How to read Json file from /src/test/resources folder using Junit runner?

Tags: java, karate

In Karate API, I can read a JSON file from "/src/test/resources" folder from a feature file location at "/src/test/java/karate/features/mytest.feature" by using below code:

```
* def content = read('../../../resources/response.json')
```

the above code runs fine when I run the feature file, but fails when I run Junit runner with Karate.run(). from the error I came to know that it is looking for the file in target folder and could not find.

Then I used below code as classpath = /src/test/java

```
 * def content = read('classpath:../resources/response.json')
```

but this too is not working,
however if I place my resources folder under Java and use below code then it works

```
 * def content = read('classpath:resources/response.json')
```

I need help in reading json file from below location
"/src/test/resources"

so far using classpath keyword, I am not able to move to  "/src/test/resources" folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A lot depends on how your Maven (or Gradle) build file is set up. So read this first: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#folder-structure

Once that is ok, you should be able to use `classpath:response.json`. Refer to the [docs](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#reading-files) also.

If you have trouble, use the [quickstart or template](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/Get-Started:-Maven-and-Gradle) projects as a reference.

Comment: I am able to resolve the issue now, thank you a lot, I used " read('classpath:response.json')" as you suggested because it will search under resources directory
also my resources folder was not marked as resources, it was a normal directory earlier